# Flex sound sampling rate

Tags: apache-flex, audio, sample-rate

I have some high quality recorded sounds that I want to use within a flex application.

I tried to save the sounds at 22050 HZ and 64BIT Stereo with GoldWave , but the weird thing is that I get this error in FLEX : "unsupported sampling rate 32000HZ " . I am 10000% sure that I saved the sound at 22050HZ 64BIT Stereo with GoldWave. I did this 2 times.

If I save the sounds at even lower sample rate than above, they work , but the quality is lost .

Can anybody tell me what software to use to make the sounds compatible for FLEX please and what frequency and bit rate should I use to maintain a big part of the quality?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem has to do with saving as 64-bit, which is pretty non-standard, and is probably confusing one of the programs. Try something more standard 16-bit integer, and if that doesn't work go with something TOTALLY standard like 44,100 kHz.